# What is the meaning of presentation of an unital associative Ring?

Tags: ring-theory, group-presentation

Let $R$ be an unital associative ring and let $f: F \rightarrow R$ be an onto ring homomorphism. Where F is some freely generated ring over the set $S$ then $<S|T>$ is called presentation of ring $R$ where $T$ is minimal set of relation.

What does it mean by relation $T$? also is surjectivity essential there?

Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know anything about presentations of *groups* ? It might be useful

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 1):

You stated in the comments that you knew about group presentations. Well here it's the same thing but with rings :

If you say that $\langle S\mid T\rangle$ is a presentation for a group $G$ it means that $G$ is the quotient of the free group generated by $S$ by the normal subgroup generated by $T$ ($T$ is a set of words on $S$).

If now you say that $\langle S\mid T\rangle$ is a presentation of the ring $R$, it means that $R$ is the quotient of the free ring generated by $S$ by the (bilateral) ideal generated by $T$. In other words, elements of $T$ are elements of the free ring on $S$, and in $\langle S\mid T\rangle$ you declare that these are $0$.

For instance $\langle x,y\mid xy-yx\rangle$ will be (isomorphic to) the usual commutative polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Surjectivuty is essential because otherwise $R$ is not generated by $S$ !